Can users pass Dummy State Accounts in Solana Program?
I'm working with a Solana program and I have the following code:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SomeStruct<'info> {
    #[account()]
    pub state: Account<'info, State>,
    ....
}

I'm initializing this state variable of SomeStruct in the initializer of the contract, which can't be reinitialized.
pub fn lock_tokens(ctx: Context<SomeStruct>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
   ...
}

lock_tokens now needs the SomeStruct to perform its internal logic. Is it possible for someone to initialize their own state account with dummy data and pass it into the contract in SomeStruct? If so, how can one do that?

If the state is similar, you can have a signer check using the addres anchor constraint to make sure that only a pre-configured address can call the IX to initialize the state
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitEscrow<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut 
        address = "public key of admin address"
     )]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    /// CHECK: checked by us
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = authority,
        space = LEN,
        seeds = [b"SOME_SEED_PREFIX" authority.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub state: Account<'info, State>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}


Hey, the idea is that state variable is same for all accounts, but i want to understand if someone can maliciously use a custom state account and send to my function, would he be able to use his dummy values like that?

updated my answer. You can use the address check for this and after the account is initialized you needn't worry about this. IF you add an edit ix, you can use the same address constraint

Hey the question is, that i dont want to edit my code, can someone still maliciously use his own account instead of using the contract defined account which we initialized in initialize function ? given that the initialize function cant be called again

with your code, as is without any constraints and if the account isn't initialized yes.

the state account is initialized already in the initilaizer function of contract, which cant be called twice
so the only question is, if someone call lock_tokens function with their own custom pub state: Account<'info, State> and pass it as argument inside  SomeStruct

consider that the state account has a variable that tells user how many tokens to lock, if he can send in his own custom pub state: Account<'info, State> in lock_tokens function through SomeStruct, then he can maybe lock 0 while contract was expecting more, i.e he hacks the contract.

If someone call lock_okens, it again would fail. Check out https://www.helius.dev/blog/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-solana-program-security and https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/security-exploits though a bit dated but still relevant.

so basically i dont need to add any other constraints here, no one can pass in their own custom account to override the already initialized state account, they have to use the contract initialized state account

can you update the answer with required data so i can approve ?
